# How do I output only new lines added in git commit id?

Tags: git, shell

How do I output only new lines added in git commit id?
I have not found the corresponding usage of `git show`

Comment: Can you provide an example of a commit (possibly from `git diff`) and the resulting filtered output you would like?

Comment: Note that `git diff` doesn't really distinguish between "new lines" and "new versions of existing lines"; the latter is represented as a deleted line and a new line. (Git itself only differentiates between "same file" and "different file"; anything else is a diff between two versions of the file.)

Comment: I have added a new answer based on the format described by you in this : _But I want to output only new added line, exclude other any information. This command will output other information, example: commit-id, Author, Date, commit-message, etc._

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references, if in doubt refer to help center [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the output by `+` in the first column:

```
git show <commit-id> | grep '^\+'
```

Answer (score 1):

The lines which are added can be identified by searching for `+` in the beginning of each line as suggested by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59695308/10155936). However, this will also display `--- a/file +++ b/file` in the output.

**One** way is to search for the colored text. In the diff output, the lines added are represented in green color.

```
git show <commit-id> --color | grep ".\[32m+"
```

Green color is represented by this `[32m` in ANSI and `\033[32m` in ASCII where `033` is the `ESC` character. (ANSI codes start with `ESC` character or escape character)

As per [hexdump](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html), `.` represents the `ESC` character in this case.

Sample hexdump:

```
printf '%b\n' 'It is \033[31mnot\033[39m intelligent to use \033[32mhardcoded ANSI\033[39m codes!' | hexdump -C
00000000  49 74 20 69 73 20 1b 5b  33 31 6d 6e 6f 74 1b 5b  |It is .[31mnot.[|
00000010  33 39 6d 20 69 6e 74 65  6c 6c 69 67 65 6e 74 20  |39m intelligent |
00000020  74 6f 20 75 73 65 20 1b  5b 33 32 6d 68 61 72 64  |to use .[32mhard|
00000030  63 6f 64 65 64 20 41 4e  53 49 1b 5b 33 39 6d 20  |coded ANSI.[39m |
00000040  63 6f 64 65 73 21 0a                              |codes!.|
```

Refer to [this](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes#general_useful_ascii_codes) for more info on the color codes in bash

**Another** way is to change the identifier (character `+`) for added lines to some other character like `~`.

Using [`show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

```
git show <commit-id> --unified=0 --no-prefix --color=never --output-indicator-new=~ | grep "^[~]"
```

Using [`diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

```
git diff HEAD <commit-id> --unified=0 --no-prefix --color=never --output-indicator-new=~ | grep "^[~]"
```

What each option does ?

- [`unified=0`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--Ultngt) : Setting lines of context to 0
- [`no-prefix`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---no-prefix) : Removing source and destination prefix
- [`color=never`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---colorltwhengt) : Show non-colored diff to avoid messing up the grep part
- [`output-indicator-new=~`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---output-indicator-newltchargt) : Change the character of added lines from `+` to `~`
- `"^[~]"` : Filter the diff output to show lines starting with `~` character

If you want to eliminate `~` from the output, then you can pipe the output to this

```
awk -F'^[~]' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: @daidai21, If you don't mind please do explain why the answer was unaccepted

Comment: I accept all your answers. But this system only one can be accepted. Sorry.
When output to a file with shell pipeline used you method, the encoding in the file is chaotic.

`git show 016955e977a3aac70cae209bb0ff12754d2868fe --color | grep ".\[32m+" > tmp`
Then open this file using vim, the result like this [images](https://s2.ax1x.com/2020/01/16/lx3X0H.md.png)
@Saurabh P Bhandari

Comment: @daidai21, I agree that the first approach is not useful when storing the result in a file but what about the second approach ?

Comment: `git show 016955e977a3aac70cae209bb0ff12754d2868fe --unified=0 --no-prefix --color=never --output-indicator-new=~ | grep "^[~]" | awk -F'^[~]' '{print $2}' > tmp`, have you tried this @daidai21 ?